# Deleted by accident bucket and now get this error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I deleted some buckets by accident, and I recreated then but I got this error. What can be it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cloud function stored these codes in Cloud storage bucket. Maybe you deleted the source bucket. You should recreated bucket and codes also.

Comment: Is there a command to recreate all?

Comment: if you sure that deletion is completed, The contents in deleted bucket are never be recreated. You have to manually insert your codes in recreated bucket.

Comment: But I can't create buckets endeded with `appspot.com` because need domain verification

Comment: I tried to reproduce by creating a function from a ZIP in a bucket, delete the bucket and then recreate and I didn't get this error. Can you add more detailed steps and specify the behaviour of the function after this error?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Cloud Function and then create a new one; this will also create a new bucket.

Comment: Can't delete the function.

Comment: Just create another one Cloud Function; likely you'd have to open a support ticket to have the broken one deleted. Also explain to them what you've did to create that problematic situation, because one could consider this as a flaw (that it's even possible to do so).